# Copy a html object and show it again

Tags: jquery, html

I need to store a html object and show it again...My code copies it but does not display it..

Requirement:
I need the `#test` to be copied, removed from the page and should be displayed again.

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    I will be copied, removed and shown again
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
    var a = $("#test")
    $( "#test" ).remove();
     a.show()
});
```

> [Sample Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w737n/2/)
>   http://jsfiddle.net/w737n/2/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: I don't think you actually want to copy it, right? you just want to save it to a variable and remove it from the document, then place it back into the document, right? I don't see where you are trying to put it back into the document.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 => I donno what is the reason but you could use it like this: **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7Qees/
- 2 => `using clone` : **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ZsDHL/

API":

- http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Hope rest helps the need `:)`

**Code** your code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "ready!" );
    var a = $("#test");
    $( "#test" ).remove();

        $('#what').html(a.html());
});
```

**code with clone**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#drpCars').clone().appendTo('#divCars1');
    $('#drpCars').clone().appendTo('#divCars2');
    $('#drpCars').clone().appendTo('#divCars3');
    $('#drpCars').clone().appendTo('#divCars4');
});
```

Comment: :I need to store the element in a webstorage in the web browser and retrieve it later when the user comes back..Basically I want to serialize and deserialize the object asis...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w737n/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $test = $("#test");

    $("#addBtn").click(function () {
        $("#container").append($test);
    });

    $("#removeBtn").click(function () {
        $test.remove();
    });
});
```

Since the element is stored in `$test`, it won't be added or removed multiple times. The same element is moved around as needed.